# Checkbox values store in char wise and it take only one items

Tags: vb.net

am developing program for checkbox item store in database. but it store in char wise and it take only one items

my checkbox values store in character wise for database. how to solve that problem

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each item As Object In CheckedListBox1.SelectedItem
        qur = "insert into list(list) values('" & item.ToString & "')"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(qur, con)
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("insert sucessfully")
        cmd.Dispose()
        con.Close()
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: my checkbox values store in character wise for database. how to solve that problem

Comment: You can control what is saved by changing wahtever .ToString resolves to in your object. Also, you don't need to open and close the connection inside the loop - just open it outside, and close it when finished. Then .dispose the connection, not the cmd. Or use the 'Using' pattern on your connection.

Answer (score 0):

The `SelectedItem` property only gives first selected item and there is no `SelectedItems` property so you need to iterate over all items and check which item is selected:

```
Try
    con.Open()

    For Each item As ListItem In CheckedListBox1.Items
        If item.Selected Then
            qur = "insert into list(list) values('" & item.Text & "')"
            cmd = New SqlCommand(qur, con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            ...
        End If
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    ...
Finally
    con.Close()
End Try
```

You also need to edit your database handling code as pointed out in comment.